# I have an error in sql trigger on update query

Tags: sql, mariadb

The follows sql trigger is not working. I got an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7'

```
CREATE TRIGGER m_check BEFORE UPDATE ON deposition
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF((new.balance-old.balance)<0 AND(new.balance-old.balance)>=-2000) THEN    
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE "40000"     
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT='Not okay';    
    ELSE    
        UPDATE deposition SET balance=new.balance WHERE acc_no = new.acc_no;    
    END IF;
END
```

I don't understand where the problem is.Help me solve this error

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what line 7 is.  However, the `update` is not appropriate.  Instead:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER m_check BEFORE UPDATE ON deposition
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF((new.balance - old.balance) < 0 AND (new.balance-old.balance) >= -2000) THEN    
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE "40000" SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Not okay';    
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is a before update trigger.  If no signal is raised and no error occurs, then the update takes place.  There is no need to explicitly `update`.

Comment: A lots of thanks @Gordon Linoff.You save me at last.Problem solved